# Does the Windows RDP on AWS Lightsail ever shut down?

Tags: amazon-web-services, rdp, amazon-lightsail, windows-server-2019, mt4

I'm running Windows Server 2019 on an AWS Lightsail instance. The specs are 8 GB RAM, 2 vCPUs, 160 GB SSD, zone is US-East-2a. I used the RDP to download, install, and run a software program (MetaTrader4 for currency trading). It continued running for a couple of weeks after I closed the RDP, which is what I wanted. I did not shut it down, just closed the RDP window.

I know it continued running because I received daily emails from the program, then all of a sudden I stopped getting the emails. I logged into my AWS Lightsail account, used the RDP to view the Windows desktop, and no programs were running.

Do AWS Lightsail instances "cycle" or reset the RDP after some period of time if I haven't interacted with the Windows desktop? I assumed that because the program I was running was actively making trades it would just keep running. I'd like to know how often I need to access the Windows RDP to keep everything up and running. Thanks!

Comment: When you use RDP it is just a remote keyboard and display, the application is not running "in" RDP.  It's possible the trading program crashed after running for a couple of weeks, because of memory or resource leaks or other long-term damage to its state.  You might need something else running to monitor it, or add a daily task to close and restart it.

Comment: Amazon Lightsail provides a virtual computer that is running the normal Windows operating system. Lightsail does not do anything to the operating system or anything running within it.